# SQL - Condition in where clause

Tags: sql

I have an input parameter of calendar year. My Table has a Date column.

If the year value is null, I send all of the rows from the table , but if it has a value, I filter the rows based on the year value. Can these 2 conditions be combined in a single query ?

Something like this : ? represents the passed in year value

```
WHERE IIF(? = NULL, YEAR(DateColumnName) = ?, 1=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `OR` condtion for such logic:

```
WHERE YEAR(DateColumnName) = ? OR ? IS NULL
```